# LDAP Connection using Spring security

Tags: spring, spring-security, ldap

Getting bad credentials message even we entered valid details. not sure why. please help me and find the below details.

LDAP_HOST=ldap://HOSTNAME:****/

LDAP_PASSWORD=PASSWORD

LDAP_PRINCIPAL=CN=Some value,OU=DAY,OU=Americas,OU=Service,OU=User Accounts,DC=legal,DC=regn,DC=net

in spring-config.xml

```
<ldap-server url="ldap://HOSTNAME:****/" manager-password="PASSWORD"  manager-dn="CN=Some value,OU=DAY,OU=Americas,OU=Service,OU=User Accounts,DC=legal,DC=regn,DC=net"/>


<authentication-manager>
        <ldap-authentication-provider
         group-search-base="OU=CON,OU=DAY,OU=Americas,OU=Users,OU=User Accounts"
         group-search-filter="CN={0}"
         user-search-base="DC=legal,DC=regn,DC=net"
         user-search-filter="user={0}"
        />

    </authentication-manager>
```

i believe it could be issue with values inside . Please help me.

Comment: Did you successfully test the connection with an ldap client? like ldapbrowser from softerra?

Comment: You might want to read [this FAQ](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/faq.html#faq-ldap-authentication). There isn't really enough information here to help you. As Hank says, you'll need to do some testing first.